# PHP - Mysql: Create variable for undefined index

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to select from a database, my question is i want to set a variable for a where clause in my query, so lets say select * FROM Foo WHERE A = '$a', but the variable has not been set previously and is from the table i am trying to select from.
So how would i do this.

PHP

```
 $FC_ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,[]);
 $FOOD_sel = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM Food_Cat WHERE Food_Cat_ID = '$FC_ID'");
```

That is how far i have got so far.

Comment: Have you tested the value of $FC_ID, what is it's value? What is not working about your supplied code?

Comment: @ThrowBackDewd my question is how do i define $FC_ID if i need to take the value from a row within the query i am about to execute

Comment: You want to query the database based on an unknown value that you want to get from the database? If that is what you're trying to do, sounds like you will need to perform 2 queries. An original one that will help you define what the $FC_ID value should be for the second query. Otherwise I don't understand what you're really trying to do.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an X/Y problem. What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax i want to tell the query to select * from (a table) where id= (the tables id)

Comment: That's what you're trying to *do*. What is it you want to *accomplish?*

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sub query for that $FC_ID value

Answer (score 0):

sub query method

$FC_ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,[]);
 $FOOD_sel = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM Food_Cat WHERE Food_Cat_ID = (select FC_ID from your table )");

Comment: But wouldn't i need to define something between the $dbc, []